# MODULE_NOT_FOUND for adaptivecards-templating

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, adaptive-cards

Although I installed (and imported) the module with the command: npm install adaptive-expressions adaptivecards-templating --save. When I go to run my application I get the following error:

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: You also need the base adaptivecards module. Its 3 in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use AdaptiveCards with templating and expressions you need to install these 3 packages:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards
https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards-templating
https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptive-expressions
```

ie

```
npm install adaptivecards adaptivecards-templating adaptive-expressions --save
```

You also have to import all 3 packages properly.

you don't necessarily need templating if you dont use it but minimum the normal adaptivecards package. Otherwise you'll run into errors permanently.